# Problemas com união de 2 vetores

Tags: c, tipagem, booleano

Eu tenho um problema para unir dois conjuntos de números inteiros em um vetor, sem a repetição de números que se encontrem no Conjunto A e no Conjunto B.
O seguinte erro é apresentado na linha 13:

> error: unknown type name ‘bool’; did you mean ‘_Bool’?|*

Trocando `bool` para `Bool` o código não é compilado, é algum erro de sintaxe?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintVetor(int Conjunto[], int Tamanho){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < Tamanho; i++)
    {
        printf(" %i ", Conjunto[i]);
    } 
}


bool Existe(int x; int Uniao[], int k){ //Onde o erro se encontra
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if(Uniao[i] == x)
            return true;
    }
    return false; 
}


int main() {
    void PrintVetor(int Conjunto[], int Tamanho);
    bool Existe(int x; int Uniao[], int k);
    int Tam, i;
    int k=0; // Variavel que controla o tamanho do Vetor Uniao a cada vez que um novo termo é adicionado

    //Definindo o tamanho do conjunto
    printf("Qual o tamanho dos conjuntos?\n");
    scanf("%i", &Tam);
    int ConjA[Tam];
    int ConjB[Tam];
    int TamUniao = (Tam*2);
    int Uniao[TamUniao];

    //Alimentando o Conjunto A
    //Adicionando Conjunto A aoConjunto Uniao
    printf("Preencha o Conjunto A\n");
    for (i = 0; i < Tam; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &ConjA[i]);
        Uniao[i] = ConjA[i];
    }
    system("clear"); //Caso Seja Linux

    //Alimentando o Conjunto B
    printf("Preencha o Conjunto B\n");
    for (i = 0; i < Tam; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &ConjB[i]);
    }
    system("clear"); //Caso Seja Linux

    //#########################
    //Print dos Conjuntos
    printf("Conjunto A:[");
    PrintVetor(ConjA, Tam);
    printf("] \n\n");
    printf("Conjunto B:[");
    PrintVetor(ConjB, Tam);
    printf("] \n\n");

    //UNiao
    for(i=0; i<Tam; i++)
    {
        Uniao[i] = ConjA[i];
        k++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<Tam; i++)
    {
        if(!Existe(ConjB[i], Uniao, k))
        {
            Uniao[k++] = ConjB[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Conjunto Uniao:[");
    for(i=0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", Uniao[i]);
    }
    printf("] \n\n");


    return 0; 

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O principal problema é que está faltando adicionar o [cabeçalho que permite usar o tipo `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void PrintVetor(int conjunto[], int tamanho) {
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) printf(" %d", conjunto[i]);
    printf(" ]\n");
}

bool Existe(int x, int uniao[], int tamanho) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) if (uniao[i] == x) return true;
    return false; 
}

int main() {
    int tamanho;
    printf("Qual o tamanho dos conjuntos?\n");
    scanf("%i", &tamanho);
    int conjA[tamanho];
    int conjB[tamanho];
    int uniao[tamanho * 2];
    printf("Preencha o Conjunto A\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &conjA[i]);
        uniao[i] = conjA[i];
    }
    printf("Preencha o Conjunto B\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) scanf("%d", &conjB[i]);
    printf("Conjunto A: ");
    PrintVetor(conjA, tamanho);
    printf("Conjunto B: ");
    PrintVetor(conjB, tamanho);
    for (int i = 0, k = tamanho; i < tamanho; i++, k++) if (!Existe(conjB[i], uniao, k)) uniao[k] = conjB[i];
    printf("Conjunto Uniao: ");
    PrintVetor(uniao, tamanho * 2);
 }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/L3T0bx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vaiahbrx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Union.c).

Algumas coisas adicionais que fiz:

- Retirei o cabeçalho que não estava usando
- Padronizei nomes das variáveis
- Declarei as variáveis perto de onde são usadas e no menor escopo possível
- Matei variável desnecessária
- Matei declaração de função desnecessária
- Matei uma lógica repetida
- Organizei melhor o código para encurtar dando mais legibilidade (aumentando onde necessário)
- E organizei para colocar a responsabilidade de cada coisa no lugar certo
- Matei comentários, se eles são necessários é porque o código está mal escrito
- Melhorei a apresentação estética
- Mudei a formatação de dados para `%d` que é mais adequada para quase todos os casos.

O que não fiz, mas deveria ter feito:

- Validar entrada de dados
- Separar partes em funções até para manter a coerência, ou matar as funções auxiliares já que outras partes que são claramente ações separadas, mas estão na `main()`
- Otimizações maiores que vai contra o que parece ser o propósito do exercício
- Outros pequenos detalhes que vão mudar pouco

E não troquei o tipo para `_Bool` que funcionaria também.